# Daisy chain audio between Windows applications - is it possible?

Tags: audio, daisychaining, tts

As a fun (robot) project I have a text-to-speech Windows 7  application which produces speech which it outputs through the normal audio out or speakers. Then I also have a vocoder running in a VST Host which gets its input from line-in or mic.

How do I daisy-chain this lot up so that the TTS output goes to the vocoder, then the vocoder's output goes to the normal audio output channel? Is this even possible?

Many thanks.